# Dialogflow - POST /entities - not working - PHP and JSON

Tags: php, json, dialogflow-es

I have a project by Dialogflow.
I would like to update my Entites using PHP and JSON. I found the following page ([1](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/entities#post_entities)) but unfortunately it does not really help me. I think my mistake is the number in the URL, but unfortunately I do not know which one to insert ..

My code is:

```
$data = new \stdClass();

$data->entries[] = array('synonyms' => array('Apfel'), 'value' => 'Apfel');
$data->entries[] = array('synonyms' => array('Salami'), 'value' => 'Salami');
$data->name = 'Zutaten';
//echo json_encode($data);


$url = 'https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/entities?v=20150910';
$content = json_encode($data);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer 9debcXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 201 ) {
    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}


curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
```

Does anyone have an idea what I can change best, so this works?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you update your question to clarify what you mean by "does not work"? Doesn't change the entity in question? Gives you an error of some sort?

Comment: Yes my Entity doesn't update. I got the following Error:

Error: call to URL https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/entities?v=20150910 failed with status 403, response {"status":{"code":401,"errorType":"unauthorized","errorDetails":"Authentication parameters missing"}}, curl_error , curl_errno 0

But, i think the Authorization Parameters are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the solution myself. Many thanks to all who helped.

The solution was as follows:
I had to get out of these two commands:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer 9debXXXXXXXXXXX"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
```

to make this command:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer 9debc126XXXXXXXXX\r\nContent-type: application/json"));
```